# Using external variables with Javascript then

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am new to javascript, have mostly spent my time writing backend java program. I am unable to figure out how to capture the current state of the scope variables when calling then, example:-

```
idList = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for(id in idList) {
    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
        // A mock async action using setTimeout
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve(10); 
        }, 300);
    }).then(function(num) { 
        console.log(id + ': ' + num); 
        return num * 2; 
    });
}
```

The output is:-

```
"5: 10"
"5: 10"
"5: 10"
"5: 10"
"5: 10"
"5: 10"
```

But I want the output to be

```
"0: 10"
"1: 10"
"2: 10"
"3: 10"
"4: 10"
"5: 10"
```

i.e want then to capture the current state of variable id.

Comment: As an aside, you should avoid using `for ... in` when iterating over an array

Comment: You need to use a block scope variable or create a closure with functions. So `for(let id in idList)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are a few solutions to this.**

The easiest to implement (given the code you provided), is to simply put a `let` before id in your for loop.

```js
for (let id in idList) { ... }
```

Since the `for...in` loop you are using is asynchronous, it is completing before the inner functions contained within the loop are returning, thus `id` will always be whatever it was when the loop finished (in this case, 5).

The reason `let` must be used instead of `var` is because the `let` statement declares a block scope local variable.

> *let allows you to declare variables that are limited in scope to the block, statement, or expression on which it is used. This is unlike the var keyword, which defines a variable globally, or locally to an entire function regardless of block scope.* ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Description))

So, `let` will work, `var` (or a global variable, as you have it) will not.

*However*, it is advised not to use `for...in` loops on arrays when the index order is important. ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in))

---

**A better solution** would be to use the `for...of` loop, which, will visit the elements in a consistent order. This is also a fairly simple change of swapping out the word "in" with "of" to create the loop.

```js
for (let id of idList) { ... }
```

---

**A more declarative solution** would be to use the forEach method available on every array created in JavaScript. This is executes a callback function for each element in the array.

```js
const idList = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

idList.forEach(id => {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
        setTimeout(() => resolve(10), 300);
    })
    .then((num) => { 
        console.log(id + ': ' + num); 
        return num * 2; 
    });
})
```

However, please note that `forEach` will always return undefined, even if you give the callback a return value. That doesn't seem to be a problem in your case here, since all you are looking to do is `console.log` the asynchronous values as they come in.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue here is with you using `for...in` and trying to iterate over the array that way. This brings up issues with the scoping of `id` and by the time your function executes, the value of `id` is already `5`.

Since the issue is with scoping, as @wrleskovec mentions in the comments we can resolve this issue by simply changing

```
for (id in idList)
```

to

```
for (let id in idList)
```

However, [we should avoid using `for...in` for iterating over arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea).

We can fix this by encapsulating `id` within a function by using a [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) on the array instead.

```js
idList = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

idList.forEach((id) => {
    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
        // A mock async action using setTimeout
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve(10); 
        }, 300);
    }).then(function(num) { 
        console.log(id + ': ' + num); 
        return num * 2; 
    });
});
```

Also as a side note, `return num * 2;` currently doesn't do anything — not sure if this is intentional or not.

Answer (score 0):

Since the method inside the loop is asynchronous, you will have to use either:

### IIFE

[Immediately-Invoked Function Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript) captures the current state so that your code would look like this.

```
for(var id in idList) {

    (function(_id){
        new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
            // A mock async action using setTimeout
            setTimeout(function() {
                resolve(10); 
            }, 300);
        }).then(function(num) { 
            console.log(_id + ': ' + num); 
            return num * 2; 
        });
    }(id);
}
```

### Async Module

Once you have understood IIFE, you can start using a module that easily handles asynchronous methods like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async)

Using this, your code would look like:

```
async.each(idList, function(id, callback) {

    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
            // A mock async action using setTimeout
            setTimeout(function() {
                resolve(10); 
            }, 300);
        }).then(function(num) { 
            console.log(id + ': ' + num); 
            callback(null, num * 2);
            return num * 2; 
        });
}, function(err, results) {

    console.log('done with results %o', results);

});
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the scoping of your for loop variable. The for loop variable is in the parent function or global scope. You can use a block scoped variable like `let` in ES6 or you would need to create a new variable scope by wrapping your loop execution into a function. You should read up about how javascript scope and closures work.

The easiest solution IMO would be:

```
    for(let id in idList) {
    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
        // A mock async action using setTimeout
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve(10); 
        }, 300);
    }).then(function(num) { 
        console.log(id + ': ' + num); 
        return num * 2; 
    });
}
```

But if you are working in a strictly pre-ES6 environment you will need to wrap the looped execution context in a function to preserve the loop iterator in scope.

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach

```js
idList = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

idList.reduce((p, id) => {
  return p.then(function(id, value) {
    console.log("%s : %s", id, value);
    return new Promise(resolve => 
      setTimeout(() => resolve(10), 300)
    );
  }.bind(null, id));
}, Promise.resolve(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
idList = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for(id in idList) {
    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
        // A mock async action using setTimeout
        //save id value
        var idValue = id;
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve({idValue: idValue, num: 10}); 
        }, 300);
    }).then(function(obj) { 
        console.log(obj.idValue + ': ' + obj.num); 
        return obj.num * 2; 
    });
}
```